# Integrate WebGL in android app

Tags: android, webgl

I have android  app which  works fine. And now I want to add some graphical features using WebGL ,but I have not a lot of experience in 3d, especially in android. I need suggestion that how would be worked my android app (I mean performance) after integrating this new feature?

And also I'd like to know in my app can I use "WebGL code", which works fine for pc browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear. It sounds to me as if you have a native Android app that you want to add 3D content to. If so, WebGL is maybe not your best bet.

WebGL is a interface to OpenGL that works through a web browser, coded with Javascript. While you can convince some mobile devices to work with it, it's typically not available through most mobile web browsers. That may change in the near future, but it's anyone's guess as to exactly when. Point being, WebGL is not a viable target for phones right now.

If you have a native Android app though (coded with Java), you can access OpenGL ES 2.0. Capability wise it's identical to WebGL, but you can access it through the platforms native language, which will typically lead to better performance. If you have a WebGL app, it should be pretty straightforward to port to Android since the APIs are largely equivalent.

If you want to start using OpenGL in your Android app, the documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html).

Answer (score 0):

Chrome experiments now have a section for mobile https://www.chromeexperiments.com/mobile.

Though you can play wide range of webGL examples in android chrome browser by enabling webgl as shown in pic below :-

[image: enable webgl chrome android]

This way you would be able to use webgl in chrome browser :-

[image: webgl android]

Unfortunately old WebView does not support webGL but [WebView V36](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#does_the_new_webview_have_feature_parity_with_chrome_for_android_) does have webGL support . You can [openGL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.learnopengles.android&hl=en) for similar purpose.